# Url and Form security in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**What's the Problem?**

> 1. Primary Key is present in Url so the data for other records can be seen easily by easily changing the Url.
> 2. Rendered html has hidden field present. Anybody can easily change other records based upon this Hidden Field.

**When I edit the page. My Url looks like below.**

```
http://localhost/Category/3
```

**and Below is the rendered Html**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/UpdateCategory" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="AmAXKmqtct6VOFbAVJhKLswEtds4VwHWjgu3w5Q8">

    <input name="CategoryID" type="hidden" value="3">

    <input  required="required"  name="Category" type="text">

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Update">

</form>
```

Please suggest some Url and Form security in Laravel 5.1

Comment: [Laravel has policies try using them](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization)

Comment: Don't use `id`, use something else say a `uuid`

Comment: @VishalSh that does not make sense weather using `id` or `uuid`

Comment: You can use the `Crypt` class with `encrypt and decrypt` functions which will help you in form submission..

Comment: @BasheerAhmed : When posting the form...I will need a unique key and based on that I can update the record. But surprisingly, in stackoverflow.com , you can view the page source for this question. and there is no hidden field. !!!

Comment: @Programmer There is no need of any hidden field while viewing the question but the edit link has id which let you go to edit question page. While editing your question then checkout the form there. There are some hidden fields out there.

Comment: Store a unique hash code for each entry. Use that for edit page url instead of id and also update the action of your form to use that field if you don't want want hidden fields in form.

Answer (score 0):

There are many worksaround which shall by handled by us to avoid such incidents.

**Fix 1 :** 
If you don't want to reach the user's by just changing the url

(i.e., Directly passing the id in url )

You shall filter the requests by

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!='')
{

}
else
{
exit;
}
```

You shall have this in your Middleware or even in your view if you wish

**Fix 2 :** Never worry about the `_token` that is visible when you see form source

It is just the token that is generated by laravel app which is to identify whether the request is from authenticated source or not.

If you edit the token and pass the form you will surely get **CSRF Token Mismatch Exception**

Infact this is one of the great feature of Laravel.

**Interesting Point :** You can also find something in the headers of the browser ;)

Happy using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) ;)